# 17.10 unlocking my session crashing my login

Tags: login, 17.10, crash, session

I have updated my desktop from 16.10 (used default lightdm) to 17.04 (used vanilla gdm + themes) to 17.10 (ubuntu gdm), all packages are up-to-date. It appears like the upgrade tore my display manager. Whenever I unlock my session after short breaks, all my work vanish and my desktop behaves like as if I just logged in. So I decided to get rid of gdm + themes and use lightdm, ~/.themes removed, same problem. There are variety of crash dumps in /var/crash, gvfsd, gnome-shell, google-chrome etc. I don't have any clue what specifically causing the crashes. I have ~300 GB of data on my hdd, so I cant simply format and reinstall the OS. Someone help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Take a backup of your data, and then do a re-install of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem after a new installation on Ubuntu 17.10.
It seems that a patch has been created. See:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789166#c16

**Note**: I did not try the patch yet. It seems that the patch has still not been released. See [post #46](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-shell/+bug/1721428).

Comment: No. It seems that the patch has still not be released. See [post #46](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-shell/+bug/1721428).